# Failed building wheel PyYAML

Tags: python, flask, pip, flask-ask

I'm trying to install flask-ask using pip

```
pip3 install flask_ask
```

and I'm getting a very long error that's in short saying

```
Building wheel for PyYAML (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
```

I'm running **python3.7.4_1** on **MacOS 10.14.5**. I've tried python 3.6 and 3.7 along with different versions of pip to no avail.

---

Below is the error message (let me know if you need more):

***Links are broken as of Feb 2023:***

- [Error Pt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67j4s.png)
- [Error Pt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKmoa.png)
- [Error Pt 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bnly.png)

Comment: `pip3 install pyyaml` — what is the error?

Comment: That very long error is what is containing the information of what exactly is wrong. The `ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyYAML` part contains zero information about the actual problem. Please also mention your OS

Comment: There's no error for pip3 install pyyaml. My OS is macOS Mojave 10.14.5.